# If $f(x)$ has an asymptote, when does the limit of the tangent lines approach the asymptote?

Tags: calculus, limits, differential-geometry, asymptotics, curves

I was looking at functions with horizontal asymptotes. By a basic definition, $f(x)$ has a horizontal asymptote at $y=c$ if
$$
\lim_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x) - c= 0 \tag {1}
$$
where the $\pm$ indicates one sign or the other, or possibly both. On the other hand, the equation of the tangent line to $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is given by
$$
y = f'(a)(x-a) + f(a) \tag{2}
$$
So my question is, given that $f$ has a horizontal asymptote at $y=c$, when does
$$
\lim_{a \to \pm\infty}f'(a)(x-a) + f(a) = c\qquad ?
$$
Or equivalently, since $\lim_{a \to \pm\infty} f(a) =c$ by our hypothesis $(1)$, when does
$$
\lim_{a \to \pm \infty}f'(a)(x-a) = 0 \tag{3}\qquad ?
$$

---

While trying to answer this question I ran into a problem with the definition of an asymptote that I've been using. As explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1938419/695196), by defining an asymptote simply as a function that satisfies the limit you may have functions such as $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ which (just by following the limit definition) has a horizontal asymptote at $x=0$, but where the continuous limit $\lim_{a \to \infty} f'(a)(x-a)$ is [indeterminate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Limit%5B%28%28-a+%2B+x%29+%28a+Cos%5Ba%5D+-+Sin%5Ba%5D%29%29%2Fa%5E2%2C+a+-%3E+Infinity%5D) since the slope $f'(a)$ will continue to oscillate indefinitely.

What *does* seem obvious to me is that given some $f(x)$ that's smooth enough, if $f(x)$ approaches the asymptote $y=c$ monotonically then the limit $\lim_{a \to \infty} f'(a)(x-a) = c$. But even though this seems obvious graphically (as the functions starts to "smooth out" into a more linear behavior) I couldn't seem to mathematically describe this, and in turn, I couldn't show that the limit in question holds.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to formally describe the above behavior such that it can be used to prove that limit  $(3)$ exists?

---

Lastly, I wanted to know how I could generalize this definition (and proof of the limit) for oblique asymptotes. Given some curve $\alpha(t)= (x(t), y(t))$, and some line $\ell :\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2  \vert ax+by -c =0\}$, if we say that $\ell$ is an asymptote to $\alpha$ as $t \to \tau$ for some value of $\tau$ when
$$
\lim_{t \to \tau} d(\alpha(t), \ell)=0
$$
where $d(\alpha(t), \ell)$ represents the distance between the curves, then, by recalling the distance from a point to a line, we can generalize equation $(1)$ as
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to \tau} \frac{\lvert ax(t) + by(t) - c\rvert}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} = 0 \tag{4}
\end{equation}

So the more general question becomes: If $(4)$ holds, then when does this also imply that
$$
\lim_{a \to \tau} \alpha'(a)t + \alpha(a) = \ell \qquad ?
$$
And if it doesn't always hold, what other hypothesis does $\alpha(t)$ need to verify such that it does hold?

---

Any and all help or ideas will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: You deal with $\lim_{|a|\to\infty}$ but you say nothing about $ x $ .

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, I didn't specify this because in that instance I'm saying that limit of the tangent-line functions $T_a(x)$ happens to tend to the constant function $g(x) = c$. So if this is true, then $$\left(\lim_{a\to \infty}T_a(x)\right)\Big\vert_{x=\zeta}  = g(x)\Big\vert_{x=\zeta}  = c$$ for whichever value of $x$ I want.

Comment: You want $\lim_{a\to\pm\inftt}F(a,x) $ , a function of two variables. is $ x $ close to $ a $ or $ x $ is fixed.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah, since in this particular case I'm claiming that the limit of the tangent lines is a constant, then $x$ can be close to $a$ or fixed or any other value since the _whole_ line will eventually tend to a constant. By fixing $x$ I would essentially be looking at the limit of the tangent lines point-by-point, but since I'm proposing that the _whole_ tangent line tends to a constant line, then whichever value of $x$ you choose to fix should give the same constant limit. 

If my understanding is wrong please let me know, but I hope I explained why I left it like it is written.

Comment: I believe this is no longer an issue for the general case I wrote at the end since I'm proposing that the limit of $T_\eta(t) = \alpha'(\eta) t+\alpha(\eta)$ should tend to another function of $t$, namely the line
$$\ell(t) = (b,-a)t + \left(0,\frac{c}{b}\right)$$
The thing is that in the horizontal asymptote case we get $a=0$ and $b=1$, so in the above equation the line $\ell(t)$ happens to be
$$\ell(t) =   \left(t,c\right), \qquad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}$$
where we see that the $y$-coordinate of the function $\ell(t)$ equals $c$ for whichever value of $t$ you want.

Comment: A function can have a horizontal asymptote and still have a derivative that behaves wildly in the limit.  Something like $\sin(x^2) / x$ for example tends to $0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ but the derivative has no limit. So the tangent line will behave wildly also.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I believe that's in the same spirit of the $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ example I put on my discussion. I got to the conclusion that I must require the asymptote approach to be monotonic and the function to be smooth for the limit to work, but I couldn't seem to formalize my ideas. Specifically, I wanted to know exactly how to formally write what the necessary conditions needed for the limit to hold are, and then (if possible) how to use this to prove that under those conditions the limit holds.

Comment: I see, I missed that.  What you can say is if $f$ is monotonic and smooth and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists then $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$. However, I think it is unclear what you mean by the limit of the *line* rather than the pointwise limit.  In some sense any two lines, if they are not equal, are infinitely far apart, because you can always find $x$ for which the corresponding $y$-values are arbitrary distant.

Comment: @JairTaylor, I understand that it's unclear. I guess "convergence" is the better word. What I mean by taking the limit of the line is somewhat "the same" as when we talk about the convergence of some sequence of functions $f_n(x) \to f(x)$, as we take $n \to \infty$, but in this case the $f_n(x)$ are the tangent lines and the $f(x)$ is the asymptote. I can change the wording of the question if this is the correct way to express the idea.

Comment: Actually what I said before was wrong: you can have $f$ monotonic and smooth and $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exist and still have $f'(x)$ pretty wild. (imagine $f$ with a lot of small but steep stair steps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer this, we need a notion of "limit" for lines. A natural choice in this setting is to parametrize non-vertical lines by slope $m$ and $y$-intercept $b$, so that a line $y = b(a)x + m(a)$ approaches $y = mx + b$ if and only if $m(a) \to m$ and $b(a) \to b$.

As you note, if $f$ is differentiable everywhere, the tangent line to the graph $y = f(x)$ at $x = a$ is $y = f(a) + f'(a)(x - a) = f'(a)x + [f(a) - af'(a)]$. This approaches $y = f(a)$ if and only if $f'(a) \to 0$ and $af'(a) \to 0$. The second clearly implies the first, since $|f'(a)| < |a|\, |f'(a)|$ for $|a| > 1$. It's also fairly clear by example that $f'(a) \to 0$ does not imply $af'(a) \to 0$.

In sum, the tangent line of $f$ at $a$ approaches $y = f(a)$ as $|a| \to \infty$ if and only if $af'(a) \to 0$.

If instead you have an oblique asymptote $y = mx + b$, the differentiable function $g(x) = f(x) - mx$ has a horizontal asymptote, so this question reduces to the previous case, and the necessary and sufficient conditions are $f'(a) \to m$ and $f(a) - af'(a) \to b$.

Comment: This is such a clean solution. Once you explained it by rearranging the terms in the line equations the conditions made total sense. +1

Comment: +1 for a good question. My first thought was "$f'(a) \to 0$". While that's true for rational functions, it's not true for all differentiable functions.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you i) translate everything to the origin and ii) work in a limited domain, so that $x$ is not allowed to be too far from the point of tangency $a$ and iii) Make some assumptions on $f$. Let's use monotonicity and concavity for example.

Let $f(x)$ be an increasing, concave-down smooth function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $L = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists.  Define the functions $$T_a(x) = f(a) + f'(a) (x-a).$$ Translate this to the origin: define $S_a(x) = T_a(x+a) = f(a) + f'(a) x$.

Claim: For any $M > 0$, as $a \rightarrow \infty$, $S_a(x) - f(x+a) \rightarrow 0$ uniformly for $x \in [-M,M]$.

Proof: First we prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$. For suppose not; then there is $\epsilon > 0$ so that for any $L > 0$ we have some $a>L$ with $|f'(a)| > \epsilon$. Since $f(x)$ is assumed increasing, $f'(a) > 0$, so we can say $f'(a) > \epsilon$. Then using the fact that $f'(x)$ is decreasing, we have

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= f(a) + f(x) - f(a) \\
&= f(a) + \int_a^x f'(t) \, dt\\ &\geq f(a) + \int_a^x f'(a) \, dt  \\ &= f(a) + \epsilon (x-a)\end{align*} which tends to $\infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ contradicting the fact that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ exists and is finite.  So $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f'(x) = 0$

Now *fix* M.  Given $\epsilon$ choose $L$ so that for $x>L$ we have both $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon/3$ and $|f'(x)| < \epsilon/(3M)$.

Then for $a > L$ and any $|x| < M$, we have \begin{align*}|S_a(x) - f(x+a)| &= |f(a) - f(x+a) + f'(a) x |\\ & |f(a) - f(x+a)| + |f'(a) x |\\ &|f(a) - L| + |L - f(x+a)| +  |f'(a)| x \\&< 2\epsilon/3 + (\epsilon/(3M)) M \\ &= \epsilon.\end{align*}

This is for a horizontal asymptote. Likely you can do a similar argument for an oblique asymptote.

Answer (score 0):

Take
$$f(x)=\frac 1x$$
then $ c=0$ but
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}f'(a)(2a-a)=0$$
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}f'(a)(a^2-a)=-1$$
and
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}f'(a)(a^3-a)=\infty$$

So, your limit $\lim_{a\to\infty}f'(a)(x-a) $ should depend on $ x $.

Comment: I'm sorry. I believe I made a poor job at explaining what I meant by "limit of a line". What I mean by taking the limit of the line is somewhat "the same" as when we talk about the convergence of some sequence of functions $f_n(x)\to f(x)$, as we take $n \to \infty$, but in this case the $f_n(x)$ are the tangent lines and the $f(x)$ is the asymptote. Using this same notation, you've showed that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(n^2) \neq \lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(n^3)$, but this is not what I meant in my question. I again apologize for the misunderstanding.